# ASP.Net Core Identity EF 5.0 restore only users to database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, database-administration, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework in my Blazor Server Project and have customized it with no problem. I do enjoy the simplicity and robustness of the Identity; however, since I am developing for deployment, I came across a small problem. In the disaster recovery, the FULL restore from an MSSQL backup works without a hitch. This type of backup is crucial if you have not changed anything in your ApplicationDbContext for the deployed Blazor Server Project. So for that matter in disaster recovery to a same state and DbContext, there is no issue, but should you have a small change from one install to another in the DbContext, or say you are upgrading the previous version of the Blazor Server Project with changes in the context, you cannot recover the users since you can only do a complete FULL restore with the previous DbContext as the Db Schema and Design.

How can I restore, or better yet, migrate the date from one instance of the DBContext to another? I tried doing a data restore from backup device, but it does not let me do the restore due to the foreign key between the user table and the user claims and user roles tables. Foreign key constraints do not permit me to restore the users with the previous generated GUID which contain vital information link to other data. Say for example one table tracks events that are created by the user, if I re-create the user, it has different GUID than what is registered in the backup.

Any help will be appreciated.

If you query the table for the ASPNetUsers you get the following:

```
    Id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               UserName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NormalizedUserName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Email                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NormalizedEmail                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  EmailConfirmed PasswordHash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     SecurityStamp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ConcurrencyStamp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 PhoneNumber                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      PhoneNumberConfirmed TwoFactorEnabled LockoutEnd                         LockoutEnabled AccessFailedCount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ---------------- ---------------------------------- -------------- -----------------
6cd26b55-b0c6-41ae-ac6c-ff9ae3242c3b                                                                                                                                                                                                                             userone@mymail.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               USERONE@MYMAIL.COM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               userone@mymail.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               USERONE@MYMAIL.COM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1              AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAECp/NfxxEWw8fbd0jIrXOGZ/v/ggPscxMIINueP2dUQAihgRwrE1a+t1os/7MwvPCg==                                                                                                                                                                             OJP4HUHN6FNCXHXETVJTDQLC6RBUCLJS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 f69a0ff7-9298-4d1f-8faa-e8ab3db3ab70                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                    0                NULL                               1              0
9eda9ba1-dd47-4308-ba62-a19381a32d56                                                                                                                                                                                                                             usertwo@mymail.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               USERTWO@MYMAIL.COM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               usertwo@mymail.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               USERTWO@MYMAIL.COM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1              AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEFcXpQREt8sfhssYHlH/hRSlk3yX/bGMCYpXpTrid+YLNMFkDr5V45MnIo0JOPmWlw==                                                                                                                                                                             YLZJSYILLPQZBFGCOJLXKFZB64YXCHIK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 c389b663-fcd1-4918-b9ed-54bc583666cc                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0                    0                NULL                               1              0

(2 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-08-06T14:19:46.8143727-07:00
```

Since the Id is a GUID generated by the EF Core Identity Table, and is linked to the other ASPNetCore tables such as UserRoles, UserClaims, Etc., how can I import user data with the old GUID that was previously generated?

**Edit Aug 12 2021**

I have found a temporary work-around for the problem. For purpose of explanation I will use APP, OriginalDB, BackedUpDevice (the bak file) and RestoredDB and NewDB.

The OriginalDB I am continuing to work on the model and ASP.Net Core/Blazor application (APP), therefore on ocassions the model changes. I have my App that when it initializes for the first time, it uses the models to create the Database on the server, should it not exist. I use migrations to create the new model to be put on the server at first run. ASP.Net Core Identity facilitates this.

So, the original problem arises only when the model is modified in the APP and the APP needs to re-apply the migration. I don't use subsequent migrations since, once the OriginalDB is in use, there is data and even if the model changes, the data will need to be copied. I have absolutely no problem with this. I can restore from the BackedUpDevice to another Database as the RestoredDB. I then use the RestoredDB to insert the data back into the NewDB, which is a freshly created copy of the OriginalDB schema and the model changes in the APP. Thus, this gives me my data, but I cannot use this method for the ASP.Net Core Identity tables since it uses Foreign Keys.

The work-around that I have found, is that I can safely delete the ASP.Net Core Identity tables, namely AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUsers, and do a copy schema and table from the RestoredDB to the NewDB. While recreating the tables using this method works, I have the problem that I have also modified these user tables, not only changing the table names, but also adding custom fields as shown primarily in [This Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0), on future iterations of the APP, there may be additional custom fields and/or changes that affect these tables. Hence why I need to see how I may just copy the RestoreDB user tables data, including the generated GUID for the user with Foreign Keys to the NewDB user tables. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I obviously don't know everything about your situation, and I don't understand some parts of your explanation at all, but **the approach you've outlined is going very far down the wrong road.**

EF Core 5.0 migrations allow a lot flexibility in how they are created, maintained, and applied.  You should leverage these features to accomplish what you want to do, rather than creating new databases and copying data into them.

Some examples that seem to be applicable to your use case:

- From [Using a Separate Migrations Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), you may want to consider having two different sets of migrations - one for local development / iteration, and one that just has migrations that take the released application from one version to the next
- From [Customize migration code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customize-migration-code), solving your problems with the automated migrations may involve customizing the automatically generated migration code.  Or creating empty migrations and writing completely custom code to perform intermediate data migrations steps
- From [Excluding parts of your model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#excluding-parts-of-your-model), you may need to exclude certain objects in one DbContext from being included in the migrations for another DbContext (for instance, if your Identity tables are coming from a different DbContext than the rest of your app tables, but you reference the Identity entities in your main app's DbContext)